# Remove all the rows containing any negative value or NA in data matrix

Tags: r

Data set contains 19972 rows and 3006 columns, how can i remove all the rows containing any negative value or NA in data matrix.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data using `dput()`?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a `data.frame` containing `NA` and negative values:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a=runif(10, -10,10), b=runif(10, -5, 5))
df$a[7] <- NA
df
```

`df` looks like this:

```
           a           b
1  -4.689827 -2.94025425
2  -2.557522 -3.23443247
3   1.457067  1.87022847
4   8.164156 -1.15896282
5  -5.966361  2.69841420
6   7.967794 -0.02300758
7         NA  2.17618508
8   3.215956  4.91906095
9   2.582281 -1.19964821
10 -8.764275  2.77445221
```

Then:

```
negative_row <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x < 0 | is.na(x)))
df[!negative_row,]
```

giving:

```
         a        b
3 1.457067 1.870228
8 3.215956 4.919061
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the code below

```
> subset(m, rowSums(sign(m) < 0) == 0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    4
[2,]    4   16    8   16
[3,]    5   25    0   20
```

where `m` is the given matrix as

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    4
[2,]    2   NA    4    8
[3,]   -3    0    6   12
[4,]    4   16    8   16
[5,]    5   25    0   20
```

**Dummy Data**

```
> dput(m)
structure(c(1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 1, NA, 0, 16, 25, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0,
4, 8, 12, 16, 20), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

Comment: @akrun I don't know either. Anyway, thanks for your support!

Comment: @akrun No worries, I just want to provide an option for readers who are interested :)